# What is the difference between subscribe and segment in OneSignal?

Tags: onesignal

As I tell you what I understood about "subscribe" and "segment" in OneSignal.

First of all, "subscribe" is users to subscribe to the specific segment, then the users are subscribed to the segment and they are dependent to the segment.

Second of all, "segment" is a group that users can be involved in, so that they are targeted when a mobile app wants to send targeted messages.

[image]

**my question**: As you can see above picture that is about an OneSignal pricing table, does "subscribers" mean that people subscribed in segments? So does it mean that 100,000 subscribers can be in segments when I paid for "Growth" tier? When I say it more specifically with an example, there are two segments("segment_fir", "segment_sec"), 100,000 users. Then is it only possible that total 100,000 users should be in each segments??

Comment: You should ask this question of OneSignal sales team

Answer (score 1):

"subscribed" means the device is opted-in/subscribed to receive push notifications.

"segments" are groups of subscribed devices based on filters.

You pay based on the number of "subscribed" push notification devices you have.

OneSignal allows you to delete "segments" of devices to manage your costs: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/delete-users

Answer (score 1):

I'm a [OneSignal PM here](https://linkedin.com/in/rubychilds1). We use the term subscriber as a device that is subscribed to one of our channels. We show this slider to primarily give an est of the potential cost of sending push notifications to their users. We do provide the ability to add more than 100k subscribers into OneSignal and within a segment. But for these large amounts, we suggest users use a higher tier that has better features and support for this volume.

Feel free to reach out to our support team to discuss more. Happy Sending!